# Does Python provide a way to access a variable beyond the nearest enclosing scope?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope

Given the example below, inspired by another from a [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36263131/4375327):

```
x = 0
def func1():
    x = 1
    def func2():
        x = 2
        def func3():
            KEYWORD x # scope declaration
            x = 3
        func3()
    func2()
func1()
```

With `global` and `nonlocal` as KEYWORD, For `x` the values are respectively `0` and `2` instead of `3`.

Does Python provides a mechanism to use the scope of `func1()` for `x` in `func3()`? Or only `global`, `func2` and `func3` scopes are accessible here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot specify a specific scope with `nonlocal`. It will always choose the nearest enclosing scope that contains the named variable.

Since Python uses lexical scoping, the only way to get into this situation is by writing the code for all the scopes yourself. (E.g., when you write `func3`, you *know* it is nested in `func2`, so you know all the variables in scope in `func2`.) Just don't reuse the same names in each scope when you write the code, and `nonlocal` will do the right thing. (We'll ignore the issue of writing such deeply nested code in the first place.)

```
x_global = 0
def func1():
    x_first = 1
    def func2():
        x_second = 2
        def func3():
            nonlocal x_first # scope declaration
            x_first = 3
        func3()
    func2()
func1()
```

---

In contrast, let's pretend Python used dynamic scoping.

```
x = 9

def func1():
    nonlocal x
    x = 3

def func2():
    x = 1
    func1()
    print(x)

def func3():
    print(x)

func2()    # Prints 3
print(x)   # Prints 9; the global variable hasn't been changed
func1()
print(x)   # Prints 3; the global variable *has* changed.
```

The variable modified by `func1` now depends on the scope in which `func1` is called.

In real Python, the above sequence would print

```
1
3
3
```

as `func1` will *alway* modify the global variable, whether it is called from the global scope or from `func2`'s local scope.

Comment: Thanks. This is not a piece of code I would use or recommend for the sake of simplicity and cleanliness), it's rather to "fill a hole" in the understanding of the language.

Comment: The key is lexical scoping; you can't accidentally "inject" an assignment into a scope that you can't see right in front of you, unlike in the case of dynamic scoping, where it's the scope from which the function is *called*, not the scope where it is *defined*, that matters.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your comment. It seems to link the use of a surrounding closing scope to an "accident", but in a static context, isn't it rather explicit, like in the sample?

Comment: Yes, that's the point of lexical scoping: if you are writing the code, you can immediately see what variables are in the current scope and in any enclosing scope. `func3` can only *possibly* access variables local to `func3`, variables local to `func2`, variables local to `func1`, and global variables in this module. It can't affect variables, say, in some function `func4` that just *calls* `func1`, because `func1` isn't *defined* in `func4`.

Comment: "In contrast, let's pretend Python used lexical scoping." I think you meant "let's pretend Python used dynamic scoping"

Comment: Apologies If I'm slow at understanding. I think I get the explanation you added.  "`func1` will always modify the global variable" because Python works with static scoping, right? If so the case I showed is a _declaration_ of nested scopes, so I didn't imply any dynamic scoping. Why then in that case it would be problematic to "jump" to the N+1 scope ? (In the case, of course, of Python would allow it.)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, yeah I understood it this way.

Comment: Because it's not necessary. Being able to jump scopes would imply you didn't know what intervening scope might prevent `nonlocal x` in `func3` from referring to `func1` as intended. But you *do* know exactly which scopes lie between `func3` and `func1`, because they are laid out right in front of you. They can't be defined somewhere else and imported at some later time. If you want `nonlocal x` to refer to `x` in `func1` and not `x` in `func2`, then just don't define `x` in `func2`: pick another name.

Comment: I would rather say that in the showed case I want to jump because _I precisely  know_ I don't want the immediate `x` variable, but the upper one. (Of course I understand such language feature would have few reasons to exist.)

Comment: You *should* know which variable you want to modify. It's fine if you don't want to use the local variable `x`, but you should know *which* variable you *do* want to modify. (Note, too, that using `global` and `nonlocal` *precludes* having a local variable by the same name. You get access to at most one variable of a given name in a given scope.)